# purrr accumulate function strange output

Tags: r, purrr

I guess this is a combination of two questions.

I'm trying to understand the `purrr::accumulate` function but having a hard time figuring out the interplay between `.x` and `.y`. I've been reading the `purrr` vignette but it's not explaining much. I don't have a programming background so a lot of it is over my head.

First thing, why do these have different outputs when they are the same call? The only difference is the `()` after `paste`.

```
accumulate(letters[1:5], paste, sep = ".")
[1] "a"         "a.b"       "a.b.c"     "a.b.c.d"   "a.b.c.d.e"

accumulate(letters[1:5], paste(), sep = ".")
[1] "a" "a" "a" "a" "a"
```

Second, what is going on here?

```
2:11 %>% accumulate(~ .x)
[1] 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2

accumulate(1:5, `+`)
[1]  1  3  6 10 15

2:11 %>% accumulate(~ .y)
[1]  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11

2:11 %>% accumulate(~ .x + .y)
[1]  2  5  9 14 20 27 35 44 54 65
```

`.x` is the accumulating value, but I guess it's not accumulating anything? It makes sense for `1:5` as `cumsum`. `.y` is the element in the list. Am I correct in interpreting `.y` as essentially `print`?

But wouldn't the first output of `.x + .y` be `4`?

Some insight would be very welcome.

Comment: In the first case, you are only using `.x`,  `cumsum(2:11)# [1]  2  5  9 14 20 27 35 44 54 65`.  So, not clear why it shouldn't be the same

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would be easier to understand when there are `print` statements

```
2:11 %>% 
   accumulate(~ {
     print("---step----")
     print(paste0(".x: ", .x))
     print(paste0(".y: ", .y))
     print(.x + .y)
    })
#[1] "---step----"
#[1] ".x: 2"  # .init or first value of the vector (as `.init` not specified)
#[1] ".y: 3"  # second value
#[1] 5    # sum of .x + .y
#[1] "---step----"
#[1] ".x: 5"   # note .x gets updated with the sum
#[1] ".y: 4"   # .y gets the next element
#[1] 9
#[1] "---step----"
#[1] ".x: 9"   # similarly in all the below steps
#[1] ".y: 5"
#[1] 14
#[1] "---step----"
#[1] ".x: 14"
#[1] ".y: 6"
#[1] 20
#[1] "---step----"
#[1] ".x: 20"
#[1] ".y: 7"
#[1] 27
#[1] "---step----"
#[1] ".x: 27"
#[1] ".y: 8"
#[1] 35
#[1] "---step----"
#[1] ".x: 35"
#[1] ".y: 9"
#[1] 44
#[1] "---step----"
#[1] ".x: 44"
#[1] ".y: 10"
#[1] 54
#[1] "---step----"
#[1] ".x: 54"
#[1] ".y: 11"
#[1] 65
# [1]  2  5  9 14 20 27 35 44 54 65
```

Here, `.x` is the one getting updated in each iteration and that value is getting passed into `.x + .y`

It is essentially similar to

```
cumsum(2:11)
#[1]  2  5  9 14 20 27 35 44 54 65
```

---

When we only pass `.x`, it is the `.init` value i.e the first element which is not getting updated as the `.f` is not doing anything

```
2:11 %>% 
    accumulate(~ print(.x))
#[1] 2
#[1] 2
#[1] 2
#[1] 2
#[1] 2
#[1] 2
#[1] 2
#[1] 2
#[1] 2
# [1] 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
```

Now, we pass `.init` a different value

```
2:11 %>%
    accumulate(~ print(.x), .init = 5)
#[1] 5
#[1] 5
#[1] 5
#[1] 5
#[1] 5
#[1] 5
#[1] 5
#[1] 5
#[1] 5
#[1] 5
#[1] 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5
```

---

Also, the difference in the first two calls, is the difference in passing the arguments.  In the first case with `paste`, `.x` and `.y` are implicitly passed, while in second `paste()`, it is only the `.x` i.e. going in to it

```
accumulate(letters[1:5], ~paste(.x, .y, sep = "."))
#[1] "a"         "a.b"       "a.b.c"     "a.b.c.d"   "a.b.c.d.e"
accumulate(letters[1:5], ~paste(.x,  sep = "."))
#[1] "a" "a" "a" "a" "a"
```

Comment: Thanks Akrun. A couple follow up questions: in the first example, running the code shows the output string, which starts with `2`, but the iterative printout skips it and goes straight to `5`. What's going on there? Second, in the last example, why are `.x` and `.y` implicitly passed without parentheses but with, only `.x` passed?

Comment: @hmhensen  It is because `.x` is taking up the value of `.init` as the first value and it is not getting updated because we are not applying any function on it.

Comment: for the second example, you just need to check `paste#
function (..., sep = " ", collapse = NULL)` and `paste()#
character(0)`    In the first case, `...` can take any number of arguments, and it implicitly takes the `.x` and `.y`, in the second case `paste()` is not doing anything as it is called without any parameters inside and so `.x` is returned as such

Comment: @akrun, please see and advise [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66423010/2884859)