# How to write a custom function directly inside purrr::accumulate2()

Tags: r, lambda, purrr, anonymous-function, accumulate

I am just trying my hands on lambda functions of `purrr` family.

Suppose I have to do some operation iteratively over result of previous iteration in vector through `accumulate` I can do it through .x and .y, where `.x` is result of application on previous element and `.y` is current element.  Also assume that the function/iteration is `2x+3y` i.e. double the previous result and add three times of current element, it can be done through like.

```
accumulate(1:10, ~2*.x + 3*.y)
 [1]    1    8   25   62  139  296  613 1250 2527 5084

#OR
accumulate(1:10, ~2*.x + 3*.y, .init = 2.5)
 [1]    2.5    8.0   22.0   53.0  118.0  251.0  520.0 1061.0 2146.0 4319.0 8668.0
```

However, I am not able to do so these type of iterations in `accumulate2`

```
accumulate2(1:5, 1:5, ~2*.x + 3*.y +.z)
Error in reduce2_impl(.x, .y, .f, ..., .init = .init, .acc = TRUE) : 
  `.y` does not have length 4
```

OR

```
accumulate2(1:5, 1:4, ~2*.x + 3*.y +.z)
Error in .f(out, .x[[x_i]], .y[[y_i]], ...) : object '.z' not found
```

What actually I understood from `purrr::accumulate` was that, it is a two argument function where first argument is result of previous iteration and second argument is vector passed into it directly.  On similar lines `accumulate2` is a three argument function where first argument is result of previous computation and other two arguments are passed directly.

Can someone tell where I am erring or am wrong in understanding the logic or what should be the correct way of doing it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `.x` and `.y` are only specified when there are two arguments.  With more than 2, we can use `..1`, `..2`, `..3` in their order of occurrence

```
library(purrr)
accumulate2(1:5, 1:4, ~2*..1 + 3*..2 +..3)
#[[1]]
#[1] 1

#[[2]]
#[1] 9

#[[3]]
#[1] 29

#[[4]]
#[1] 73

#[[5]]
#[1] 165
```

Comment: Got it thanks. Can you also please tell the reason why the default output of accumulate2 is a list?

Comment: https://github.com/tidyverse/purrr/issues/774 `simplify(accumulate2(1:5, 1:4, ~2*..1 + 3*..2 +..3)) --> [1]   1   9  29  73 165`

Comment: @AnilGoyal it is not reducing to a vector and as far as I know, there is no similar methods with suffix as in map to return a specific type

Comment: Upvoted this answer then! when I didn't quite understand this stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Now that we know how to use it for the sake of completeness:

```
Reduce(function(x, y){
  2 * x + 3 * vec[-1][y] + vec2[y]
}, init = vec[1], 
seq_along(vec)[-length(vec)], accumulate = TRUE)

[1]   1   9  29  73 165
```